# Handling ELMAH errors from malformed requests in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah

We just installed a big ASP.NET MVC project (converted from ASP.NET).  Everything is working great, but we're seeing a huge number of errors via ELMAH that are coming from malformed bot/spider requests.  They are not malicious - just malformed.  Examples are requests for a product page without a ProductID and requests for a product page where the ProductID is not an integer.  In these cases, I have an action method set up that expects an integer ProductID and an error is thrown if ASP.NET MVC sees anything else.

I don't really want to hack my action method to accept strings or nullable ints and write code to do conversions and handle missing parameters.  That seems like a lot of work to handle errors that real users won't see.

I know I can filter out these errors in ELMAH, but I was wondering if there's a more graceful way to handle this.

Comment: I wanted to add that I was hoping for some kind of setting that tells ASP.NET MVC to return a 404 if it finds a matching route for the request but it can't find an action method that matches the specified route parameters.  I'm guessing this doesn't exist though.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the errors that are recorded in ELMAH.

General article on error filtering - 
http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/ErrorFiltering

Some samples - http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/ErrorFilterExamples

You can put something like this in your global.asax (or thereabouts).

```
    protected void ErrorLog_Filtering(object sender, ExceptionFilterEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Exception.GetBaseException() is WebFaultException)
        {
            var exception = ((WebFaultException) e.Exception.GetBaseException());

            if(exception.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotModified)
                e.Dismiss();
        }
    }
```

I think you might be better with the web.config approach, expliciatlly listing the URL's that get hit with the known regex patterns. That way you're filtering won't be to harsh, leading to false positives.